# How can I do the quick sort with two lists (use list comprehension) in python?

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

I need to do a quicksort with two lists and merge them into one list and output the result. In the program, `lista = numbers = (1,2,3,4,5)` and `listb = numberaa = (6,7,8,9,10)`

And the result is `[1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5]`

Here is my code so far:

```py
def quicksort(lista, listb):

    if len(lista) <= 1:
        return lista
    elif len(listb) <= 1:
        return listb
    else:
        pivota = lista[0]
        pivotb = listb[0]

        lesser = quicksort([x for x in lista[1:] if x < pivota], [y for y in listb[1:] if y < pivotb])
        greater = quicksort([x for x in lista[1:] if x >= pivota], [y for y in listb[1:] if y >= pivotb])

        result = lesser + [pivota] + [pivotb] + greater

        return result

numbers = (1,2,3,4,5)
numberaa = (6,7,8,9,10)

print(quicksort(numbers, numberaa))
```

I think my program has two problems:

1. If the length of `lista` is shorter or equal to the length of `listb`, after `lista` is sorted , the rest of the elements in `listb` will not be sorted.
2. The output result is not in increasing order.

What should I do to solve the problems?

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow it is expected that you show us a honest attempt to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: Thanks for providing your code. The next step is to attempt [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) it yourself.